# Get headers value does not work in Web API Controller C#

Tags: c#

Here is my code, l_request.Headers does not contain anything.I inserted header value in Postman.

```
HttpRequestMessage l_request = new HttpRequestMessage();
var l_headers = l_request.Headers;  
string l_headerValue = "";
if (l_headers.Contains("Content-Over"))
{
   l_headerValue = l_headers.GetValues("Content-Over").First();
}
```

Comment: What do you expect that `l_request` should contain if you created as empty? Where is this code located? Is this a Controller in an MVC app? A Web API App? Please be more specific and add relevant details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of initializing new instance you should use the static Request.
If this is a filter the request is in the context object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. @Daniel Rapaport.

I changed my code as below and got it.

```
public string GetHeaderValue()
{
        var re = Request;
        var headers = re.Headers;

        string l_headerValue = "";
        if (headers.Contains("Content-Over"))
        {
            l_headerValue = headers.GetValues("Content-Over").First();
        }

        return l_headerValue;
}
```

Or

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Content-Over"]
```